# Configure Keycloak with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, keycloak

How can I configure Keycloak with Spring Boot to give free access to some resources, but, at the same time, to have AuthorizationContext available in Spring Boot application (AuthorizationContext is available only when policy-enforcer-config is enabled)?

Answer (score 0):

By using the Policy Enforcer you could do the following to have protected and unprotected endpoints:

```
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[1]=admin
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=secure
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/secure
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].name=insecure
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/insecure

keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=PERMISSIVE
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].name=Secure Resource
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].path=/secure
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[1].name=Insecure Resource
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[1].path=/insecure
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[1].enforcement-mode=DISABLED
```